# How to inject service to helper after a promise has been fulfilled?

Tags: ajax, ember.js, promise, ember-cli, es6-promise

I am developing a simple Ember app, which retrieves all language strings from an API. I have setup a service with a `translate()` method, and injected that service into a helper. The problem is that the property I want to use it not available in the helper, because when it's used, the promise hasn't been fulfilled yet. How can I access the property in the helper after it has been loaded from the service?

Service (app/services/i18n.js):

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    locales: null,
    init() {
        this._super();

        Ember.$.getJSON('/api/recruiting/locales').then(function (response) {
            this.set('locales', response.data);
        }.bind(this));
    },
    translate(key) {
        // This causes the problem: locales property has not been loaded yet at this point
        return this.get('locales.' + key);
    }
});
```

Helper (app/helpers/translate.js):

```
export default Ember.Helper.extend({
    i18n: Ember.inject.service(),
    compute(params/*, hash*/) {
        var i18n = this.get('i18n');

        return i18n.translate(params[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found a 'solution'. I am recomputing the helper every time the 'locales' property changes. This is how my helper looks now:

```
export default Ember.Helper.extend({
    i18n: Ember.inject.service(),
    onLocalesInit: Ember.observer('i18n.locales', function () {
        this.recompute();
    }),
    compute(params/*, hash*/) {
        var i18n = this.get('i18n');

        return i18n.translate(params[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Ember Octane the result would be something like this. Note observers are considered bad practice, so you'd need to implement some kind of change listener in the `i18n` service to trigger changes in the `i18n.locales` variable.

```
import Helper from '@ember/component/helper';
import { inject as service } from "@ember/service";

export default class Translate extends Helper {
  @service i18n;

  init() {
    super.init(...arguments);
    this.i18n.addChangeListener(this.localeChanged);
  }

  willDestroy() {
    super.willDestroy();
    this.i18n.removeChangeListener(this.localeChanged);
  }

  localeChanged = () => {
    this.recompute();
  }

  compute([key]) {
    return this.i18n.translate(key);
  }
}
```